# Cannot remove "from {{APP_NAME}}" from One Signal Web Push Notifications (Safari iOS)

Tags: ios, node.js, safari, onesignal

I am using One Signal for push notifications for web on my PWA. But the push notifications I get, have this "from {{MY_APP_NAME}}" on them when tested on an iOS device. I am trying to get rid of it but cannot find anything.

what can I do to achieve this? Please HELP!

I tried sending the following request body to the One Signal create notification API from my nodeJS server,

```
const notification = {
    contents: {
      'en': "my content",
    },
    headings: {
      'en': "my title"
    },
    subtitle:{
      'en': ``
    },
    web_url: "www.google.com",
    chrome_web_icon: "app icon",
    include_external_user_ids: [participant.id],
    ios_badgeType: "Increase",
    ios_badgeCount: 1,
    channel_for_external_user_ids: "push"
  };
```

and still the "from {{MY_APP_NAME}}" appears on the notification body